# How to include Assimp with CMakeLists?

Tags: cmake, assimp

I'm unable to include the external library [assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) into my project using CMakeLists.

I got it working by doing:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries/include)
target_link_libraries(MyProject assimp)
```

but I don't want to use add_subdirectoy since it adds it to my IDE. (Visual Studios 2013)

Why am I unable to just include the assimp include directory and link it with my project like this?

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries/lib32/)
target_link_libraries(MyProject assimp)
```

Comment: If I were to use `assimp` I'd fix its broken config-module support so it would be this simple to link to it: `find_package(assimp REQUIRED)` then `target_link_libraries(MyProject assimp)`

Comment: Yeah that would be perfect! But I have never worked with config-module's before.. I'm very new to CMake

Comment: Doesn't matter. I don't recall a single distribution (tried it on Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora) where `find_package()` worked for the Assimp library.